# On mac, how to detect mouse right click on taskbaricon of wxpython application

Tags: wxpython, mouseevent, right-mouse-button

I have running simple wxpython application reside in Taskbar/System-tray area that shows popup menu when user click on it. Work fine except I need to show popup menu when user click right mouse button on Taskbar icon (mac).

Binding right click like:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_UP, self.onRight)
```

do not do anything.

Comment: Do you mean the menu bar, or the Dock? There's no direct equivalent of the system tray on Mac.

Comment: I meant menu bar which is created using wx.TaskBarIcon class. Binding right click like: 

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_RIGHT_UP, self.onRight)
do not do anything.

Comment: It seems wxPython which has known issue of not firing the event on right click. [See this link](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14646)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the event directly. The wx.TaskBarIcon has a method to add a right-click menu, [although the wxPython docs are a bit light-on](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TaskBarIcon-class.html), the [wxWigets docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtaskbaricon.html) explain it quite well.

If the C++ docs confuse you, have a look at the excellent [Mouse vs Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/12/13/wxpython-101-creating-taskbar-icons/) tutorial on taskbar icons.

**ETA**:

Note that by default wxPython gives you the wxWigets menubar item on Mac, which as far as I can tell, [only captures a left-click event](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/src/osx/cocoa/taskbar.mm?view=markup) (line 353). You can get a dock taskbar item if you construct your item passing the right magic words:

```
wx.TaskBarIcon(wx.TBI_DOCK)
```

This can capture left and right clicks.

Comment: On Windows7, right click menu works fine without binding any event. On Mac, left click menu works by default and I need to show same menu on right click too. I'm not able to find any documentation that explain how to show task bar menu on right-click on MacOS

Comment: Take another look at that Mouse vs Python tutorial. The second code example includes a `MailIcon` class that subclasses wx.TaskBarIcon and overrides CreatePopupMenu.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue of wxwidget 2.9.4 in which event is not triggered when taskbaricon is right clicked.
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14646